# `Required` attribute not working with <form> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, required

My `required` attribute doesn't specify that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

HTML:

```
<!-- Modal Content -->
            <form class="modal-content2">
                <div class="container3">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                    <hr>
                    <label for="firstName"><b>First Name</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName" required>

                    <label for="lastName"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastName" required>

                    <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

                    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

                    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" onfocus="this.value=''"
                        required>

                    <label for="psw-confirm"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" id="cfmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="psw-confirm" onfocus="this.value=''"
                        required>

                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="aboutus.html" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms &
                            Privacy</a>.</p>

                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn2">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="signupbtn" onclick="signUp()">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function signUp() {
    if (document.getElementById("password").value == document.getElementById("cfmpassword").value) {
        var users = new Object();
        users.firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        users.lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        users.username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        users.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        users.password = document.getElementById("password").value;


        var postUser = new XMLHttpRequest(); // new HttpRequest instance to send user details

        postUser.open("POST", "/users", true); 

        postUser.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        postUser.send(JSON.stringify(users));

        //go to the logged in page
        window.location = "main.html";
    }
    else {
        alert("Password column and Confirm Password column doesn't match!")
    }
}
```

As the `required` attribute does not work, users can continuously submit empty forms and those will be stored in my SQL database

I don't have a `<button type="submit">` in the form as this prevents me from using `windows.location`.

I am new to programming, can someone please give some suggestions (with explanations) on what to do to fix this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot! (I am using vanilla JavaScript for this)

Comment: You really should put the code in the question....

Comment: well onclick does not honor html5 validation.

Comment: there are too many `buttons` in the form

Comment: you never use css ?

Comment: If you remove those 3 lines than you have a JavaScript error! If you remove those 3 lines than you have a JavaScript error! Why? because you still use `credentials` in the Ajax call and that will throw an error. So the call will not happen and the submit will run.... Attach your code like I suggest in my answer

Comment: @CBCH And I explained in the answer it is not the function, it is the implementation.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have added in the codes.

Comment: Why is AJAX even used? What is the content of `/users` and why are you not checking for a valid return before redirecting to `resreview.html`?

Comment: I have backend javascript codes to communicate with my database to get or send the data so I used AJAX. I am still unfamiliar with how to check for a valid return so I am just redirecting the user straight to the `main.html` for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `required` attribute does not work because your form is not submitted. You need to specify a button with a `type="submit"` or `<input type="submit">` to submit your `form`.

I suggest you to move the `signUp` function inside the `form` tag like this with an `onsubmit` event:

`<form onsubmit="signUp(event)">`.

Then add this to you Javascript function:

`function signUp(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ... your old code
}`

Comment: Submitting with javascript seems not to work. Am speaking of formElement.submit(). It bypasses html required attribute

Answer (score 3):

For me, I see a number of possible issues. I have tried to remove them with the following sample code. I am assuming that `/users` will return *something* useful for checking and alerting the member if there is an error with the accessing of `/users` or the processing of the data.

The use of the `required` attribute of `<input>` will do nothing obvious in your code as the `<button>` has an `onclick=signUp()` call which will triggered before the browser check. With your current code the form values (present or not) will still be sent to `/users` as there is no testing for those values.

You need to move the `signUp()` call to the `<form>` if you want the browser check to be run.

To test this, removing the `onclick=signUp()` in the `<button>` will show you a browser tip window saying the value is needed.

As you are insisting on using AJAX to post the form data, moving the check to the `<form>` submit is idea and personally, I would still be checking the values - just good practice.

The next issue is you are not waiting for the return of a success or fail response from `/users`. In fact, you are blindly redirecting to `main.html`. If there is an error, the user will never know. This is a very bad user experience.

This is corrected in the sample code by checking for a response with a call-back, checking that response value and then alerting the member or redirecting if there is no error.

```js
var users = {};

function ajaxPost(url,postData,callFunc) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if(! http){
   return false;
  }
  http.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if((http.readyState == 4) && (http.status == 200)) {
      if(callFunc){
        callFunc(http.responseText);
      }
    }
  }
  http.open('POST',url,true);
  http.send(postData);
}

function validResult(str) {
  if (str == "valid") {
    // go to the logged in page
    window.location = "main.html";
  } else {
    console.log("invalid result, let the user know");
  }
}

function signUp(e) {
  if(e){e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();}
  
  var d = document.getElementById("signupForm").querySelectorAll("input");
  var i, max = d.length;
  // Quick check for values only. No check for the format of the values.
  // This is good practice as a browser may still ignore the `required`
  // attribute.
  for(i=0;i<max;i++) {
    d[i].value = d[i].value.trim();
    if (d[i].value) {
      users[d[i].name] = d[i].value;
    } else {
      // An alert would be better for the user here.
      console.log("Missing value for ["+ d[i].name +"]");
      // Go no further if there is a missing value.
      return;
    }
  }
  // at this point, all values added to the users object.
  console.log("users:["+ JSON.stringify(users) +"]");
  // Send the data and wait for a return value from /users
  // --- remove comment on the following line to post ----
  //ajaxPost("/users",JSON.stringify(users),validResult);
}

window.onload = function(){
  var c = document.getElementById("signupForm");
  if (c) {
    c.addEventListener("submit",signUp,false);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="signupForm">
<label for="firstName"><b>First Name</b></label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName" required>
<p>
<label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
<p>
<button id="submit" type="submit">Check and submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic of HTML5 validation. You have it on button click and that runs before the validation happens. This shows you that the onclick runs and the onsubmit does not. Use the correct event.

```js
function loginSubmit () {
  console.log('loginSubmit')
}

function loginClick () {
  console.log('loginClick')
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="loginSubmit()">
  <input name="foo" required />
  <button onclick="loginClick()">click</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way **[required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)** attribute works is it determines whether the element its assigned to has a value length higher than a zero, if that statement is false (meaning the value length of zero) then upon submitting the form it focuses that element as its "required" to be fulfilled.

Here is an example with JavaScript and how checking input fields could work inside it.

```js
const form   = document.querySelector('form[action="signup.php"]'); // Form
const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');                      // All input elements inside the form
const submit = form.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');         // Submit button inside the form

// Add onclick event to the form button
submit.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault(); // This prevents the button from submitting the form the traditional way
 submit_form();          // but instead our way
});

function submit_form()
{
 // We iterate through the form input elements
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
 {
  // We check if the current element has
  // the attribute required and if so
  // we proceed with checks
  if (inputs[i].hasAttribute('required') && inputs[i].value.length == 0)
  {
   inputs[i].focus();                            // We focus on the required element
   alert(inputs[i].placeholder+' is required!'); // Alert the user that the element is required
   break;                                        // Break from the loop
  }
  else
  {
   if (i == (inputs.length - 1)) form.submit();  // If the loop's i variable counter hits the same value as the
                                                 // input elements length then it means all fields are filled
  }
 }
}
```

```css
form {
 width:300px;
 margin:auto
}

form button,
form input {
 width:100%;
 height:48px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-size:18px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

form input:focus {
 background-color:#f2dfb7;
}
```

```html
<form action="signup.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
 <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
 <input type="email" name="email_repeat" placeholder="Email Address (Repeat)" required>
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
 <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
 <input type="text" name="birthday" placeholder="Birthday (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
 <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```